# Get class attribute data foreach instance of a class

Tags: c#

I am not sure if this is possible with C#, but is it possible to store information in an attribute that is related to the instance of a class?

So, I have the following class with the field `Initialized`, as seen here:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class GameObjectAttribute : Attribute {
  internal bool Initialized = false;
}
```

I then use this to add the attribute to the class:

```cs
[GameObject]
public class Player {

}
```

Now, in this class, is it possible to modify the data in the attribute for each individual instance of the class like in this pseudo code:

```cs
internal class Core {
  async void Tick() {
    while (isRunning) {
      foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects) {
        // Get attribute information
        var refToAttribute = gameObject.... // Somehow get information
        if (!refToAttribute.Initialized) {
          // Do some stuff
          refToAttribute.Initialized = true;
        }
      }
      await Task.Delay(1);
    }
  }
}
```

### Edit

When coming from a TypeScript world, I can return a new instance of a class when the class is created:

```
export function GameObject() {
  return function (constructor: T) {
    return class extends constructor {
      initialized = false;
    }
  }
}

@GameObject
export class Player {
}
```

so now, in my loop I have access to `instance`, however `Player` does not have access.

Comment: If this is for a game, the last thing id be doing is worry about reflection. Why not just a standard data structure in memory?

Comment: What would be a use-case for this? Why not a simple property IsInitialized in class Player? Or if you can't modify the Player class, simply put the initialized instances in a HashSet.

Comment: I am working on an idea that I have for a game engine (more so for the learning experience). So, `Initialized` wouldn't be available to the game that is using the library.

Comment: Sounds like you want an [`internal` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal).

Comment: @JohnWu Assuming that OP is developing that game engine, the player object would probably be part of the game itself that is consuming the engine. The way I understood this is that OP wants to add additional data about “game objects” that is only private to the game engine; but the game object itself is still owned by the game. So internal would be exactly the opposite of what is asked for here.

Comment: You might need to think about a decorator pattern where each `Player` object is wrapped in a `GameObject` before being handed back to the engine. That way the concrete instance type is limited in what it can do and you can extend as much metadata as you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, in this class, is it possible to modify the data in the attribute for each individual instance of the class

No, attributes are attached to the *class*, not to instances of said class. There is only a single instance of the attribute and that instance is attached to the class `Player`. You can access the attribute from the player instance, but only by looking at the attributes that are attached to the type. So it is really not anything that you could use to provide additional information for any particular player instance.

What you can do in a statically typed language is to wrap the value. Something like this would achieve what you are trying to do:

```
public class PlayerGameObject
{
    public bool IsInitialized { get; set; }
    public Player Player { get; set; }
}

// …
foreach (var gameObject in gameObjects)
{
    if (!gameObject.IsInitialized)
    {
        var player = gameObject.Player;

        // do some stuff
        gameObject.IsInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, I created a list in the core of the game and stored each item in that array so when I loop over each item every tick I use this reference with the object and initialization status.

Comment: I am not sure if this would help in anyway or not, but can I have an attribute constructor that adds a constructor to the `Player` class?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to store information in an attribute that is related to the instance of a class?

No. Attributes are part of the definition of a class, not instances of it. It's impossible for the same reason that a method can't be public for one instance of a class but private for another instance of the same class.

Information about an instance of a class can only be stored in its fields and properties.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a base class instead.

```
//Your framework
abstract class GameObject
{
    internal bool Initialized { get; set; } = false;
}


//Inside program that uses the framework
class Player : GameObject
{
}
```

Now the `Player` class has a property than only your code can access.

```
//Your framework
void Initialize(GameObject obj)
{
    if (!obj.Initialized)
    {
        //Do something
        obj.Initialized = true;
    }
}

//Inside program that uses the framework
var player = new Player();
if (player.Initialized) //Compile-time error
```